# common setup for python crc (6.1.1) and stm32 hardware CRC unit?

Tags: python, stm32, crc32

I'm sending data from python code to stm32g0xx mcu.
I'm using stm32 hardware CRC computing unit and https://pypi.org/project/crc/ as the other side.
Unfortunately I can't catch the common setup for both sides.

The mcu side is configured in the default way:

```
            hcrc.Init.DefaultPolynomialUse = DEFAULT_POLYNOMIAL_ENABLE;
            hcrc.Init.DefaultInitValueUse = DEFAULT_INIT_VALUE_ENABLE;
            hcrc.Init.CRCLength = CRC_POLYLENGTH_32B;
            hcrc.Init.InputDataInversionMode = CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_NONE;
            hcrc.Init.OutputDataInversionMode = CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_DISABLE;
            hcrc.InputDataFormat = CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES;
```

On the python side, I'm trying every setup with the same polynomial 0x04C11DB7 (CRC32, BZIP2 and POSIX) but haven't succeeded yet.

Can you please recommend me a better way instead of trying every possible combination?

Thx

Comment: Try online CRC32 calculators that produce CRC32/MPEG-2 (not just CRC32). I think this is what actually is in STM32. Also, remember about endianness when comparing, bytes may seem in reverse order. Link to online CRC32/MPEG-2 I used to compare against: https://crccalc.com/?crc=24002&method=crc32&datatype=ascii&outtype=dec

Answer (score 0):

The magic formula for the python code to be compatible with the STM32 default is:

```
from crc import Calculator, Configuration

config = Configuration(
    width=32,
    polynomial=0x04C11DB7,
    init_value=0xffffffff,
    final_xor_value=0,
    reverse_input=False,
    reverse_output=False,
)
```

Thanks to [@Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5932454/ilya) who confirmed my own thoughts I already had at the time.